# Problema con mismas pantallas Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo un problema, dos celulares del mismo tamaño de pantalla, solamente uno tiene la barra de botones incluida en la pantalla, y se ve para el costado.

Esta es la pantalla donde se ve mal si pueden ver esta como corrida para un costado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la pantalla donde se ve bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_primera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="srf.lec.noctambuloss.Primera"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoo">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/titulo"
            android:text="Noctambulos"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bolichesybaresbutton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
            android:background="@drawable/baresyboli" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="70dp"

            android:layout_height="44dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mapabutton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mapaa" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonsugerencia"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sugerencias" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonprevia"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/previex" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttoncontacto"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/contactanos" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que se vea igual para todas las pantallas.

Comment: Hola. No puedes usar medidas para la altura y la anchura, no medidas fijas porque entonces pasa lo que te esta pasando a ti. Tienes que jugar con los pesos de los layout en caso de ser linearLayout, o con sus posiciones en caso de usar RelativeLayout, cosa que te recomiendo. Si quieres hacerlo bien de verdad, entonces usa constraintLayout, pero poniendo medidas en el alto y el ancho de los distintos layout nunca se va a ver igual en todos los smarthphone.

Answer (score 0):

Se ve a un costado porque en realidad tu layout contiene valores fijos, por ejemplo en el segundo bloque de elementos tienes  `android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"` y después `android:layout_marginRight="15dp"` , incluso estas haciendo uso de pesos innecesariamente, con esto no puedes centrar los elementos en todos los tamaños de ancho y densidades posibles de dispositivos!.

En este caso elimina los margenes o padding innecesarios agrega a tu contenedor de botones `android:gravity="center"`, por ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
```

Es importante eliminar los margenes fijos, esto para que tengas una distribución uniforme independientemente del tamaño o densidad de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realicé un cambio a tu layout para que veas los cambios necesarios, incluso es en realidad más sencillo evitando agregar propiedades innecesarias :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_primera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="srf.lec.noctambuloss.Primera"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoo">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/titulo"
            android:text="Noctambulos"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bolichesybaresbutton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/baresyboli" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mapabutton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mapaa" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonsugerencia"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sugerencias" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp" />

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonprevia"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/previex" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttoncontacto"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contactanos" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```